# API error when someone deletes message reacted by bot Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm new to the programming world and I decided to start learning JavaScript, first with Discord bots. How can I fix my bot that stops working when someone deletes or edits the message?

````
    if (message.channel.id === 'ChannelID') {
        message.react('✅')
                .then(() => { 
        message.react('❌')
                });
}
    if (message.channel.id === 'ChannelID') {
        message.react('⭐');
}
    if (message.channel.id === 'ChannelID') {
        message.react('⬆️')
                .then(() => {
        message.react('⬇️')
                });
    }
});```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the promise rejection of `Message#react()`

```js
message
   .react(...)
   .catch(console.error);
```